# how to split pandas rows based on different character combination

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need a help

I will like to write a script in python where string stored in a row is split in different rows based on certain characters

I am trying to extract everything between "a." and ";" (and similarly between "b." and ";" and so on to different rows)

For example  (data is stored in pandas dataframe)

| c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sta | a.xxx i. gh ii. kj ;b.yyy; |
| 2 | Danny | a.xxx;b.y,c.z; |

---

---

is split as

| c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sta | xxx i. gh ii. kj |
| 2 | Sta | yyy |
| 3 | Danny | xxx |
| 4 | Danny | y |
| 5 | Danny | z |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the solution below, which uses regex to parse the string and grab all data between semi colons

```
# set up dataframe
data = {
    "c1":  [1, 2],
    "c2": ["Sta", "Danny"],
    "c3": ["a.xxx;b.yyy;", "a.xxx;b.y;c.z;"]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# parse string column
df["c4"] = df["c3"].str.findall(r"\w.([^;]+)")

# use explode to create a new record for each item found in c3
df = df.explode("c4")
```

Comment: Hi - It works but for example if i have, a. xxx i. abc ii. de ; b. yy , I would just like to split based on a. and b. but the above code is also splitting i. and ii. and that is a challenge

Comment: hey, I think we just need to adjust the regex. Could you send over 2 more quick examples of sample strings with the expected input -> expected output, where output is array of what is extracted

https://regex101.com/

Comment: I have updated the question above to give an example

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.extractall` with the `\.(?P<c3>[^;,]+);?` regex and `join`:

```
df2 = (df.drop(columns='c3')
         .join(df['c3'].str.extractall(r'\.(?P<c3>[^;,]+);?')
                       .droplevel(1))
      )
```

output:

```
   c1     c2   c3
0   1    Sta  xxx
0   1    Sta  yyy
1   2  Danny  xxx
1   2  Danny    y
1   2  Danny    z
```

###### only after a|b

```
df2 = (df.drop(columns='c3')
         .join(df['c3'].str.extractall(r'(?:a|b)\.(?P<c3>[^;,]+);?')
                       .droplevel(1))
      )
```

output:

```
   c1     c2                 c3
0   1    Sta  xxx i. gh ii. kj 
0   1    Sta                yyy
1   2  Danny                xxx
1   2  Danny                  y
```

Comment: Hi - It works but for example if i have, a. xxx i. abc ii. de ; b. yy , I would just like to split based on a. and b. but the above code is also splitting i. and ii. and that is a challenge

Comment: check the update